# Error: Could not find or load main class mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar : Why?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to learn JDBCs. But every time I try running my program I keep getting this error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar
```

I've downloaded the MySQL Connector/J and installed the driver by placing MySQL-connector-java-version-bin.jar in the PATH.

The `mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar` file has also been placed in the folder that's got the source code.

Here's my code

```
import java.sql.* ;

public class Program1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        String password = "abc123" ;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance() ;

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_test1", "root", password) ;

            Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement() ;  

            ResultSet resultSet = stmnt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblStudents") ;
            while(resultSet.next() == true) 
            {
                String stdID = resultSet.getString("StudentID") ;   
                String stdName = resultSet.getString("Name") ;      
                
                System.out.println(stdID + " | " + stdName);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exceptions -> \n" + e + "\n") ;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I compiled and ran the program in the terminal using `java -cp .; mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar Program1`.

The first few times I ran the program, it worked. And now it doesn't.

Comment: @rkosegi I'm sorry, but that's no different from my command. I think you've been mistaken for the full-stop at the end of that sentence being part of the command

Comment: Your command should be (assuming windows) `java -cp ".;mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar" Program1`, or `java -cp ".:mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar" Program1` on linux

Comment: see updated comment, `"..."` is  important here

Comment: @rkosegi I'm using Windows. And yeah it works. Thank you very much. However, I've got to say the command I used was one that I got from a tutorial. Is it no longer used now?

Comment: well don't trust every tutorial you come across.

Comment: If that tutorial still proposes `Class.forName(...)`, it must be outdated for years.

Answer (score -1):

Bad java calling syntax.

What you probably wanted to do was:
java -cp ./mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar Program1.

The line you have above is effectively treating your mysql.jar as the JAR having the class to load and NOT as the library it needs (which is what you wanted)

Comment: This will try to load class `Program1` from `mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar` as this JAR is only element in classpath. Won't work.

Comment: @user12669945 No, what you stated doesn't work

Comment: Forgot to add in the period (.) but looks like you guys figured it out above. The "." is a reference to the current directory. Semi-colon separator for multiple references. Glad you got it figured out.